# How to create a dynamic nested json that can be stored and reloaded and edited afterwards?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I want to provide templates that can later be edited by a user.
Therefore, it should be a human-readable .json object.

Example of a template containing only one field:

```
{"template_name": "sample_name",
"attribute_fields":
[{"attribute_name": "banana",
  "attribute_tags": ["chiquita", "pinkylady"], 
  "attribute_numbers": [[1, 2, 3, 4] [5, 6, 7, 8]]}]
}
```

I want to expand this json dynamically, as sometimes there will be more fields added to it - so there should be more "attribute_fields"

like this:

```
{"template_name": "sample_name",
"attribute_fields":
[{"attribute_name": "banana",
  "attribute_tags": ["chiquita", "pinkylady"], 
  "attribute_numbers": [[1, 2, 3, 4] [5, 6, 7, 8]]},
{attribute_name": "apple",
  "attribute_tags": ["applejack", "applepie"],
  "attribute_numbers": [[123, 45] [666] [5, 5, 5, 5]]}]
}
```

So far, I've done this by creating an empty defaultdict,

```
empty_template = collections.defaultdict(list) 
#yes I used a list.. don't know if there would've been a better option, just tried it and sticked to it
empty_template["template_name"].append(template_name)

looks like this
{"template_name": "sample_name"}

or, printing it, it looks exactly like this:
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'template_name': ['sample_name']})
```

and then creating a new defaultdict with all the desired attributes, then appending this new defaultdict (new_attribute_dict) to the old defaultdict (template_to_be_extended).

```
def add_attribute_to_template:
new_attribute_dict = create_new_attribute_dict(attribute_name, attribute_tags, attribute_numbers)
 template_to_be_extended["attribute_fields"].append(new_attribute_dict)


#create_new_attribute_dict looks like this:
    # create empty dictionary
    attribute_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)

    # add all attribute properties
    attribute_dict["attribute_name"] = attribute_name
    ... and so on
```

After that, I json.dumps this extended template and put it into my database. Until here, everything seems ok (but I really think there should be a prettier way to achieve this?).

After I read it back with json.loads, I have to make a defaultdict out of this json string again, so I can append key-value pairs (attribute_fields). This is where all things get really shitty and I don't know what to do. I try it this way:

```
template_to_be_extended = collections.defaultdict(lambda: json.loads(template_persistence.get(template_name))) #template_persistence returns the file from my database

extended_template = template_creator.add_attribute_to_template(template_to_be_extended,
                                                        attribute_name, attribute_tags, attribute_numbers)
```

But I really have no clue. Would've thought that I could get a defaultdict again, without using the lambda, but this throws errors (TypeError: first argument must be callable or None) - so I made it callable.. ugh..

This way, I get a AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append', so I tried to make a defaultdict out of the extended_template too

```
extended_template = collections.defaultdict(lambda: template_creator.add_attribute_to_template(template_to_be_extended,
                                                        attribute_name, attribute_tags, attribute_numbers))
```

errors are gone, but printing the extended template only returns an empty {}.

Stuck on this problem for hours and can't see anything by now. Maybe stared at it for too long.. 
Would be happy with all hints or other ways to achieve the result (it's important that I can use the lists in the deserialized json object later).

Thanks in advance

kalsari

Comment: your second data structure doesn't look syntactically correct

Comment: Neither is the first.

Comment: braces got lost by editing the original to a "small example" - hope it's correct now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will take the liberty of restructuring the way you store templates and propose the following (sample) structure:

```
{
    "template1": [
        {
            "attribute_name": "banana",
            "attribute_tags": ["chiquita", "pinkylady"],
            "attribute_numbers": [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
        },
        {
            "attribute_name": "apple",
            "attribute_tags": ["applejack", "applepie"],
            "attribute_numbers": [[123, 45], [666], [5, 5, 5, 5]]
        }
    ],
    "template2": [
        {
            "attribute_name": "fwafaw",
            "attribute_tags": ["fawg", "gawggwa"],
            "attribute_numbers": [[22]]
        },
        {
            "attribute_name": "vccbx",
            "attribute_tags": ["vzvvxz", "wgagaw"],
            "attribute_numbers": [[123, 66], [5, 5]]
        }
    ]
}
```

Basically you keep the templates in a dict and each key represents the template name where as the value is a list of attributes.

You can use `pickle` to store the whole thing as binary in a file from which you can retrieve it as it was before, avoiding JSON serialization/deserialization.

Example code:

```
import pickle
from collections import defaultdict

# initialize the templates variable
templates = defaultdict(list)

# add the first template
templates['template1'].append({
    "attribute_name": "banana",
    "attribute_tags": ["chiquita", "pinkylady"],
    "attribute_numbers": [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
})

# store the templates data to a binary file
with open("templates.data", "wb") as pf:
    pickle.dump(templates, pf)

# retrieve the templates from the binary file
with open("templates.data", "rb") as pf:
    retrieved_templates = pickle.load(pf)

# let's inspect the retrieved templates, it will be exactly like the initial structure
print(retrieved_templates)

# let's append a new attribute to the template
retrieved_templates['template1'].append({
    "attribute_name": "apple",
    "attribute_tags": ["applejack", "applepie"],
    "attribute_numbers": [[123, 45], [666], [5, 5, 5, 5]]
})

# restore the templates data
with open("templates.data", "wb") as pf:
    pickle.dump(retrieved_templates, pf)

# re-retrieve the templates
with open("templates.data", "rb") as pf:
    retrieved_templates_second = pickle.load(pf)

# will display with the updated attributes
print(retrieved_templates_second)
```

If you were to run this in console, you would have:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'template1': [{'attribute_name': 'banana', 'attribute_tags': ['chiquita', 'pinkylady'], 'attribute_numbers': [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]}]})
```

and after that

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'template1': [{'attribute_name': 'banana', 'attribute_tags': ['chiquita', 'pinkylady'], 'attribute_numbers': [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]}, {'attribute_name': 'apple', 'attribute_tags': ['applejack', 'applepie'], 'attribute_numbers': [[123, 45], [666], [5, 5, 5, 5]]}]})
```

This code has the purpose to outline what you are trying to achieve, so if you are to hide these operations and generalize them under functions and classes, try to keep the flow presented in this script.

Comment: well this is so much cleaner than my approach, I will try this out. Thank you very much! :)